# hiding files with Windows "hidden" attribute in msys2 "ls"

Tags: windows, command-line, ls, msys2

I'm running [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/) on Windows 11:

```
$ uname -a
MINGW64_NT-10.0-22621 couch-potato 3.4.9.x86_64 2023-09-15 12:15 UTC x86_64 Msys
```

And I have it configured to use my Windows home directory (`/c/Users/<username>`) rather than the default home directory supplied by msys2 (`/home/<username>`), because unfortunately I'm using some software which [requires it to be set up this way](https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/install/#windows_1).  (See `sed` command in step 7.)

```
$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
# Begin /etc/nsswitch.conf

passwd: files db
group: files db

db_enum: cache builtin

db_home: windows
db_shell: cygwin desc
db_gecos: cygwin desc

# End /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

The problem is that Windows clutters up the `C:\Users\<username>` home directory with its own files.  So when I do `ls` in my home directory, I see a bunch of crud such as `NTUSER.DAT` files.

I can mostly solve this problem with something like:

```
alias ls="ls --hide='ntuser.*' --hide='NTUSER.*'"
```

However, to do it properly, I'd want to add a bunch of other stuff to the list, like AppData, NetHood, PrintHood, etc.

And this just feels like an inelegant solution.  All of the files I don't want to see are helpfully already marked with the "hidden" attribute in the Windows filesystem.  So what I would like is for `ls` to not show files that have the "hidden" attribute.  Unfortunately, looking at the command-line options for `ls`, there doesn't appear to be an option for doing that.

Is there a way to do this that I'm unaware of?